# Serve contacts stored in CSV via CardDav protocol?

Tags: python, webdav, carddav, radicale

I have multiple CSV files with contacts. Each file belongs to a different user. I'd like to give users an option to read contacts using `CardDav` protocol. It should be READ-ONLY.

I'm considering [radical server](https://radicale.org/v3.html#getting-started) but I think it handles storage automatically.

Is there a way to do that without implementing the protocol from scratch?